# How to extract XML data real time between a server and a client on a LAN without socket connection

Tags: php, xml, sockets, tcp, camera

How are you doing?
I have two devices on LAN setup for security purpose. An alarm processing device and also IP camera. I have integrated both systems together.

I used php socket to connect to the alarm processing device in other to get the XML file that contains alarm information (data) below is the code that achieved that;

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

//Creating Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
   // echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
} else {
   // echo "OK.<br />";
}

//echo "Attempting to connect to the socket'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 10001);
flush();
if ($result === false) {
   // echo "socket_connect() failed.<br />Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
  //  echo "OK.<br />";
}
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Host: 127.0.0.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml; encoding=UTF-8\r\n";
$in .= "Accept: application/xml\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r<br />\r<br />";
$out= '';
while (socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in))){

file_put_contents("intrusion.txt",socket_read($socket, 4096));
    $out = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("intrusion.txt",1,NULL,2))or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
```

I processed this code by abstracting some information needed to trigger camera and display live feed on a web browser.

The problem now is that i have been using the simulator to test my code when I tried the php socket connect on the real device (alarm processing device) it says tcp error 10061; machine actively refused connection to it.

In my course of finding the solution I realized it could be firewall blockage which I disabled on my PC but yet nothing happened and also it could be because a client has been connected to the port, I'm trying to open, which is true but I can't disable the client because it displays graphical information of the alarm.

So here are my two questions;
How can I resolve the tcp error code 10061 or

what script using php can i use to access this XML data between the existing client connected to the server without connecting to the server port ( on this I can use Wireshark to sniff the XML data but i can't save it in real time, can only manually extract it which will not work because it's a real-time setup)

................Updated code.................

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "192.168.43.50:10001");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS);

while (file_put_contents("intrusion.txt",curl_exec($ch))){
    $out = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("intrusion.txt",1,NULL,2))or die ("Error: Cannot create object");
    //print_r ($out)."</br></br>";
//$doc = new SimpleXMLElement ( $out );

if (isset ( $out->DeviceDetectionRecord )) {
    /*  $devname = "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->DeviceIdentification->
        DeviceName."</strong>" . PHP_EOL."</br></br>\n";
        //echo "Device:" . $devname;*/

    $identity= "<strong>". $out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        ID ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "ID:" .$identity;
    $detect = "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        DetectionEvent ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "DetectionEvent:" . $detect;
    $date= "<strong>".$out->DeviceDetectionRecord->Detection->
        UpdateTime ."</strong>". PHP_EOL."</br></br>";
        echo "UpdateTime:" .$date;

        $deviceName = $out->DeviceDetectionRecord->DeviceIdentification->
DeviceName;
        $zone = explode('.', $deviceName)[2];
        $hyper = explode('.',$deviceName)[1];

        $camIP = array(
                                    'Z1'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7FxORx05Ns', // :if port is needed
                                    'Z2'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00A4vjZ7dkY',
                                    'Z3'    =>  '192.168.43.52',
                                    'Z4'    =>  '192.168.43.53',
                                    'Z5'    =>  '192.168.43.54',
                                    'Z6'    =>  '192.168.43.55',
                                    'Z7'    =>  '192.168.43.56',
                                    'Z8'    =>  '192.168.43.57',
                                    'Z9'    =>  '192.168.43.58',
                                    'Z10'   =>  '192.168.43.59',                                   
                                    'Z11'   =>  '192.168.43.60',
                                    'Z12'   =>  '192.168.43.61',
                                );

        if ($zone == 'Z1' | $hyper == 'H1'){
            echo '<script>window.open("/integration/camerapull.php", "_blank", "width=400,height=500")</script>';

                                /*BEGIN PLAYER webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" startspan 

                echo "<object ID='MediaPlayer' WIDTH='320' HEIGHT='270' CLASSID='CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95' STANDBY='Loading Windows Media Player components...' TYPE='application/x-oleobject' CODEBASE='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112'>";

                    echo "<param name='autoStart' value='True'>";

                    echo "<param name='filename' value=".$camIP[$zone].">";

                    echo "<param NAME='ShowControls' VALUE='False'>";

                    echo "<param NAME='ShowStatusBar' VALUE='False'>";

                    echo "<embed TYPE='application/x-mplayer2' SRC=".$camIP[$zone]." NAME='MediaPlayer' WIDTH='320' HEIGHT='270' autostart='1' showcontrols='0'>";
                    echo "</embed>";
                    echo "</object>";

                    /*webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" endspan end PLAYER */

                /* echo '<script>window.open("http://$camIP[$zone], "_blank", "width=400,height=500")</script>';

            echo "<video '_blank' width='320' height='240' autoplay controls>";
                                            echo "<source '_blank' src=".$camIP[$zone].  "type='video/mp4'>";
                                        echo    "<object width='320' height='240' '_blank' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf'>";
                                            echo    "<param name='movie' '_blank' value='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf' /> ";
                                                echo "<param name='flashvars' '_blank value='config={'clip': {'url':".$camIP[$zone]."',' 'autoPlay':true, 'autoBuffering':true}} /> ";
                                            ///<p><a href='%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
                                        echo"   </object>";
echo "</video>";
        */

            }elseif($zone == 'Z2' | $hyper == 'H1'){
            echo '<script>window.open("/integration/camerapull.php", "_blank", "width=400,height=500")</script>';

                /*

                echo "<video target='_blank' width='320' height='240' autoplay controls>";
                                            echo "<source target='_blank' src=".$camIP[$zone].  "type='video/mp4'>";
                                        echo    "<object width='320' height='240' target='_blank' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf'>";
                                            echo    "<param name='movie' target='_blank' value='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf' /> ";
                                                echo "<param name='flashvars' target='_blank value='config={'clip': {'url':".$camIP[$zone]."',' 'autoPlay':true, 'autoBuffering':true}} /> ";
                                            ///<p><a href='%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
                                        echo"   </object>";
echo "</video>";

                /****** Camera code 
                            function openCamFeed($zone)
                            {
                                $camIP = array(
                                    'Z1'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7FxORx05Ns', // :if port is needed
                                    'Z2'    =>  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00A4vjZ7dkY',
                                    'Z3'    =>  '192.168.43.52',
                                    'Z4'    =>  '192.168.43.53',
                                    'Z5'    =>  '192.168.43.54',
                                    'Z6'    =>  '192.168.43.55',
                                    'Z7'    =>  '192.168.43.56',
                                    'Z8'    =>  '192.168.43.57',
                                    'Z9'    =>  '192.168.43.58',
                                    'Z10'   =>  '192.168.43.59',                                   
                                    'Z11'   =>  '192.168.43.60',
                                    'Z12'   =>  '192.168.43.61',
                                );
                            //echo $zone.'<br /><br />';
                                if ($zone != '')
                                {
                                    //header("Location: http://".$camIP[$zone]);
                                    echo "<video target='_blank' width='320' height='240' autoplay controls>";
                                            echo "<source src=".$camIP[$zone].  "type='video/mp4'>";
                                        echo    "<object width='320' height='240' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf'>";
                                            echo    "<param name='movie' value='http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf' /> ";
                                                echo "<param name='flashvars' target='_blank value='config={'clip': {'url':".$camIP[$zone]."',' 'autoPlay':true, 'autoBuffering':true}} /> ";
                                            ///<p><a href='%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
                                        echo"   </object>";
echo "</video>";/*
<!--- BEGIN PLAYER --->

<!-- webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" startspan ---->

<object ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="270" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">

<param name="autoStart" value="True">

<param name="filename" value="rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx">

<param NAME="ShowControls" VALUE="False">

<param NAME="ShowStatusBar" VALUE="False">

<embed TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="270" autostart="1" showcontrols="0"></embed></object>

<!-- webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" endspan ---->

<!--- end PLAYER --->
                                //echo "<iframe align='middle' height='450px' width='900px' target='_blank' src=".$camIP[$zone]."></iframe>";
                                //
                                }
                            }


                openCamFeed($zone);
                **********/
            }elseif($zone == 'Z1' | $hyper == 'H2'){
            echo '<script>window.open("/integration/camerapull.php", "_blank","width=400,height=500")</script>';

            }elseif($zone == 'Z2' | $hyper == 'H2'){
            echo '<script>window.open("integration/camerapull.php", "_blank", "width=400,height=500")</script>';

            }
}
else {
    print_r ($out)."</br></br>\r\n";
    //echo "Nothing detected" . PHP_EOL;
} 

    flush();
    ob_flush();




}

?>
```

Thank you guys 
Rasheed

Comment: I would assume that there are some login credentials you would have to pass to the camera, even if these are the default values.  Check the software that displays the images and see if that has any login username and password.

Comment: Nigel I so much appreciate all your selfless effort. Have resolved the issue. I used elseif statement and echo using javascript window.open to echo the page that bear the camera redirect ttoo. and everything works , But the issue now is the device i initial connection to , to receive the xml, the post is being used by another device and always refuse connection to my own. So i needed how to capitalize on the existing connection between the duo to receive my XML

Answer (score 0):

here is solution using curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://websiteURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=".$xmlcontent."&password=".$password."&etc=etc");
$content=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you didi, really appreciate you, i tried it but it kept rolling without a response, check the updated code i posted above, if you could help me edit it. Thanks